# Azure Hybrid Connections for a SaaS web application

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, saas

I have a SaaS web application running on Azure as a Web app that uses the on-premises resources of the customer. To access his server I use Hybrid Connections, so they can link their server to my application using the Hybrid Connection Manager and an EndPoint connection string.

Recently Microsoft updated the Hybrid Connections and now there's a limit of how many connections a Web App can use at the same time. This is quite a problem for my SaaS architecture. You also need to log in on the Hybrid Connection Manager with your Azure credentials (which is not something you can hand over to your customers).

I was wondering if there's an alternative for the Hybrid Connections or a way you still can have as connections many as you want (without using the old connection with a BizTalk service)?

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there's an alternative for the Hybrid Connections or a way you still can have as connections many as you want (without using the old connection with a BizTalk service)?

In short answer : no, azure web app has the limits of the hybrid connections now.

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#hybrid-connections-and-app-service-plans), the number of hybrid connections usable in the plan is according to the service plan tire.

The only hybrid connections you can now make are the new hybrid connections. They are only available in Basic, Standard, Premium and Isolated pricing SKUs. There are limits tied to the pricing plan.

Basic       5
Standard    25
Premium     200
Isolated    200

While there is a limit on the number of hybrid connection endpoints that can be used in an App Service Plan, each hybrid connection used can be used across any number of apps in that App Service Plan. That is to say that if I had 1 hybrid connection that I used in 5 separate apps in my App Service Plan, that is still just 1 hybrid connection.

Comment: What if I need for example 300 connections, would it be a good option to make 2 app services? Or is that a bad alternative solution? If so, is there an other technology like a WCF service I could use to establish a connection from my web app to on-premises resources (like a REST API) without the need to configure the server firewall and port settings?

Comment: As far as I know the  limits of the hybrid connections is according to the app service plan. If you create two app in one app service plan, the  limits of the hybrid connections is still 200. Besides, if you want to exceed the limits, I suggest you could try to connect with azure support team.

Comment: Okey, that's indeed a better idea. Thanks!